Images or content documents are broken in both Chatter and Apex Page when Cross-Origin Embedder Policy (COEP) is enabled
When turning on COEP, content documents  show up as broken in both Chatter and my apex pages that display them.
The error I am receiving is
Failed to load resource: net::ERR_BLOCKED_BY_RESPONSE.NotSameOriginAfterDefaultedToSameOriginByCoep

The URL that SF is blocking is my sandbox URL

Example URL: https://<SANDBOX_NAME>.sandbox.file.force.com/sfc/servlet.shepherd/version/renditionDownload?rendition=<VERSION>

I tried

Adding the URL of the image to the CORS Whitelist
Adding crossorgin to the img tag

I do see that there is an open issue around profile images not showing up when COEP is enabled.
Is there another way I can get the images to show up when COEP is enable?
